# Short description in news box

Tags: news

I make a IT news portal. In homepage I am going to place 3 boxes per row with image, title, short description and button "See more >"

I'm not sure to add a short description in box. Maybe only an image and title are enough?

Version with short description and without it:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgf0K.jpg

Comment: This all comes down to your editorial decisions, if your titles convey enough information on their own then description are not required.

Comment: Remember users may not be familiar with some of the content, so if you have the space available a little description has better chances of hooking a new reader

Answer (score 1):

I'd add the description. It's just a little more information that will help the user decide if that article is the resource they are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is purely your case communication related. If you can write good enough headings, or if the headings will be long enough, you don't need descriptions.

It also depends upon your general design. If you will have classic layout for news style site, standard is WITH description. 
If you will make metro style based design with overlays on picture, standard is only heading WITHOUT description.

It is also pretty much not important and it should not affect your User Experience.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a third option: Instead of going with the description, just show a quick draft of the article in question. So you can "read more" whenever you're interested in it or not.

The title should be descriptive enough of the news. However; a quick overview of the article's tone might act as an incentive for the user to actually continue reading the article.